# Hosting Whatsapp bot Using Pywhatkit with Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I used the Pywhatkit python library to automate sending whatsapp messages, it's working very well in localhost, I realized I have to keep my PC on 24/7 for this to work. So I thought about hosting on Heroku (I don't know if that is possible), so I put it on heroku, but every time I try to run my script in heroku, I get the following error.

Heroku Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pywhatkit
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pywhatkit/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pywhatkit.whats import (
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pywhatkit/whats.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pyautogui as pg
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 249, in <module>
    import mouseinfo
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mouseinfo/__init__.py", line 223, in <module>
    _display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'DISPLAY'
```

##### Code (Files)

requirement.txt

```
pywhatkit==5.4
```

test.py

```
import pywhatkit

try:

    pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly("+1*********",
                                    "Hello from NewYork")
    print("Successfully Sent!")

except:

    print("An Unexpected Error!")
```

Comment: Trying to set an environment variable, `$ export DISPAY='SOME VALUE'`

Comment: @RahulKP Please How can I do that?

Comment: Since you are using Heroku, you can set the environment value.

Comment: @RahulKP Ran $ export DISPLAY=':0' in bash on heroku but I get another error Xlib.error.DisplayConnectionError: Can't connect to display ":0": [Errno 2] No such file or directory. I also set it manually under Config Vars in settings on heroku, same new error.

Comment: @AkintolaAbraham to my knowledge pywhatkit opens whatsapp web in browser and sends message if you are logged in already right?

Comment: @Msvstl yes exactly, that's how it works.

Comment: @AkintolaAbraham then I don't think it's possible on heroku, since browser is not available on heroku and you are not logged in.

Comment: @AkintolaAbraham Instead you can get a whatsapp business account and try to use those apis to automate the process.